# WooCommerce Variable Product issue after updating prices

Tags: wordpress, templates, woocommerce, product-variations

This just started happening yesterday. I changed my price and now when a customer selects a color item, this pops up underneath the item.

It doesn't prevent the customer from ordering, but it looks horrible right underneath the product when they are about to proceed to the checkout.

Any information would be helpful.

```
{{{+data.variation.variation_description+}}}
{{{+data.variation.price_html+}}}
{{{+data.variation.availability_html+}}}
```

Here is a link to the product / image. Choose Either black, or white and you will see this code above pop up underneath the product.

Live website link to a product: [**`sparkslide.com (iphone-66s)`**](https://sparkslide.com/product/iphone-66s/)

Screenshot:
[image: product page screenshot]

Thanks

Comment: This code come from the woocommerce template [**`single-product/add-to-cart/variation.php`**](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/2.6.0/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/variation.php) and normally should be replaced by some dynamic data: See [this WordPress related documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Javascript_Reference/wp.template) … Something has happen, that make this occur. Go in Admin menu > WooCommerce > system status, to check up your configuration. Once checked, change to **Tools** tab and "WC Transients" try **Clear transients**. This issue is very strange!

Comment: Also Empty you browser cache and reload your product page to see if something change… I doesn't guaranty anything…

Comment: Does the problem persist with a default theme? If no, then perhaps you have a theme template override that is causing problems.

Comment: I have been using this theme for over a year now. This just happened yesterday when i changed the price on the items. I updated all plugins and deleted the unnecessary ones! The only woocommerce error in the system status is:  5.5.9-1ubuntu4.20 - We recommend a minimum PHP version of 5.6. See: How to update your PHP version (red)

Answer (score 0):

This is a hack.

```
.woocommerce-variation.single_variation div{display:none;}
```

But it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

Your theme template is out of date with the newest version of WooCommerce. Or the component in X isn't working correctly. Update your theme first, and if it doesn't work, contact Themeco. Otherwise, your best bet is the quick CSS hack offered by Jaime